# Waiting on a Monitor with a retroactively configurable timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, stopwatch

Would this be a valid pattern for implementing a timeout for waiting on a condition? The goal is to allow another thread to set a timeout after `SomeMethod` has already been called.

```
readonly object someLock = new object();
int timeout;
bool timeoutEnabled;
bool someCondition;

void SomeMethod()
{
    lock (someLock)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (!SomeCondition)
        {
            if (!timeoutEnabled)
                Monitor.Wait(someLock);
            else
            {
                long timeToWait = timeout - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                if (timeToWait > 0)
                    Monitor.Wait(someLock, (int)timeToWait);
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Do things.
    }
}

void DisableTimeout()
{
    lock (someLock)
    {
        timeoutEnabled = false;
        Monitor.PulseAll(someLock);
    }
}

void SetTimeout(int newTimeout)
{
    lock (someLock)
    {
        timeout = newTimeout;
        timeoutEnabled = true;
        Monitor.PulseAll(someLock);
    }
}
```

The problem I see is the fact that I'm not stopping the `Stopwatch`. I'm assuming it has enough range to not overflow for any reasonable amount of program execution time. Otherwise, the method might wait for a lot more than the given time limit, throw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception on wait or do other bad things.

`Stopwatch`'s `ElapsedMilliseconds` property is of type `long`. However, there's no way the underlying counter can actually work for almost 300 million years without wrapping around.

Is there a way to find out what the limit actually is? Or is there a smallest time period that `Stopwatch` is guaranteed to work with? Should I expect it to be a couple of minutes, hours, days or years?

#### Update

I was finally able to find some more info about what is guaranteed with `Stopwatch`:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

  > The Stopwatch class assists the manipulation of timing-related
  >   performance counters within managed code. Specifically, the Frequency
  >   field and GetTimestamp method can be used in place of the unmanaged
  >   Win32 APIs QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter.

  This makes me conclude that the `Stopwatch` uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` to
  get its underlying counter.
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408.aspx

  > How often does QPC roll over?
  >   Not less than 100 years from the most recent system boot, and potentially longer based on the underlying hardware timer used. For most applications, rollover isn't a concern.

  So yeah, not a concern at all.

Comment: “The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the underlying timer mechanism” (From MSDN). I take it as "as long as the system clock is still running, `Stopwatch` will be working fine, until *Y3K*, which is 1000 years from now:)".

Comment: @kennyzx Found some more info and updated the post. Looks like they guarantee 100 years.

Answer (score 2):

If you introduce a new `ManualResetEvent`, you can do `WaitHandle.WaitAll()`. This would require you to use WaitHandles overall instead of Monitor.

In this case you would distinguish between the event you initially waited for and the event 'hey, you need to reconsider the timeout'.

Comment: Great suggestion! Very flexible. Only downside to the solution is that it requires you to invoke the power of the kernel. :)

Answer (score 0):

what about Backgroundworker ?? for it you can enable the cancelationpending

```
public BackgroundWorker myWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
myWoker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
myWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(waitingMethod);
myWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(finalChekc);
```

here the function that will run in a different thread

```
private void waitingMethod(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    bool endConditions = false;
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    while (!endConditions && !worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        endConditions = checkEndConditions();
        if(worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            endConditions = true;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        thread.Sleep(20);
    }
}
```

there the function that will be called when the thread finish. You can check if it finished because it finished naturally, or someone canceled it.

```
void deviceSearchCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.Cancelled)  blablabla
}
```

Then from wherever you can just call the BackgroundWorker and cancel it

```
myWorker.CancelAsync();
```

If you want to cancel it from a different thread you can make it static.

Comment: 1. Run 1000 of these and you have a lots of CPU time wasted by threads that wake up to see if it's the time to stop. 2. Average reaction time is 10ms.